# Bulk file upload Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload, bulk

I have around 1500 images which are dynamically generated in my local server. I want these to upload to Appengine's datastore. How can i do this? any help, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**BlobStore**

You can use the [blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html) if you have a billing account.
So I assume to use the bolbstore API to upload it in chunks with a client tool over http.
Before every upload, you can ask the blobstore to give you an unique upload URL to post MIME multipart posts to it.
There is a size limit for requests I think.

**Simple DataStore**

If you store your images in the datastore, you can use a [python tool](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) somehow to synchronize.

Comment: changed my system architecture to solve this.!anyway thanx for your response, kisp,